# Regex to match comma separated numbers or stop (Full match only)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match comma separated numbers, but if any of the numbers is not valid stop regex and don't match it at all.

Here is an example that should be matched

```
3123123213212,3123123263212,3173123213212
```

This string shouldn't be matched

```
3123123213212,3123123263212dad,3173123213212
```

So at least one invalid number should lead to unmatched regex.

What I've tried is the following expression

```
(?:(\d+)(?=\,|\s|$))+
```

Here is Regex101 link

https://regex101.com/r/JpuA5X/1

The problem that even if some number is invalid it matches other numbers, but this is not acceptable.

How can I modify my regex to get desired result ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I haven't mentioned, I need to group every single number.

Comment: Why not use a good Tim's regex and then - if a test returns true  - split with `,`? You cannot get arbitrary number of groups using just one capturing group in the pattern.

Comment: What do you mean you need to group every single number? What are you expecting as the output result?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need lookarounds for this. Anchors are sufficient:

```
/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     # Start of string
\d+   # Match an integer number
(?:   # Start of non-capturing group
 ,    # Match a comma
 \d+  # Match an integer number
)*    # Repeat group any number of times (including 0)
$     # End of string
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that I need to group every single number.

Comment: You can't do that in a single regex, at least not in JavaScript. You need to do it in two steps - first, make sure the overall string is valid using above regex, then extract all the numbers using `/\d+/g`.

Answer (score 2):

You could look for start and end and the parts between.

```js
var regex = /^(\d+,)*\d+$/;

console.log('3123123213212,3123123263212,3173123213212'.match(regex));
console.log('3123123213212,3123123263212abc,3173123213212'.match(regex));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that I need to group every single number.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I'm not sure it's possible to match and capture what you want without including some other (undesirable) captures, ones that would include the comma.

Instead you can test the string, and if it matches, split the string into an array using the comma as the delimiter. If the string doesn't match, return an empty array or some other value that you would like to symbolize "no match".

```js
var regex = /^\d+(,\d+)*$/;
var valid_string = '3123123213212,3123123263212,3173123213212';
var invalid_string = '3123123213212,3123123263212dad,3173123213212';

console.log(regex.test(valid_string) ? valid_string.split(',') : []);
console.log(regex.test(invalid_string) ? invalid_string.split(',') : []);
```

Comment: Matches only two numbers

Comment: @bxfvgekd updated my answer.